# Working with multiscreen output in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, pagination

In Rails Console, my output is often a hash so long it fills several screens.

I can press the space bar to get to the bottom of the hash. At that point, the screen flashes END, but I can't get "past" the bottom of the hash to enter my next command.

Likewise, I can't scroll up to review the contents of the hash.

What should I do?

BTW, my Gemfile includes:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'hirb'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks as less-like interface.

Try `arrow up/arrow down/page up/page down` keys for navigation and press `q` to quit the hash view.